# Nginx + Varnish 4 return 200 empty response for all requests

Tags: tomcat, nginx, varnish

I have nginx as a front end reverse proxy + varnish cache + web app backend set up, requests are going through nginx - > varnish - > backend, i can see logs at all sides, but it returns a blank 200 response for all requests.

my /etc/default/varnish.vcl

```
vcl 4.0;


backend jira {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "27988";
}


sub vcl_recv {

   set req.backend_hint = jira;

   if (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|swf|css|js)$") {
      unset req.http.Cookie;
      return (pipe);
  } else {
      return (pass);
  }

}


sub vcl_backend_response {

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.(css|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico)$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 30m;

     #Set Grace Time to one hour
       set beresp.grace = 1h;
    }
}
```

my nginx conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name jira.lan.mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:6081/;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;


    }

}


80 - nginx port
6081 - varnish port
27988 - backend server(jira) port
```

requests to `jira.lan.fongwell.com` go to nginx first, then varnish , then backend if not static resources, but all return empty 200 response.

If I bypass nginx and go to varnish, eg. `192.168.0.119:6081`, where `6081` is varnish port, then things work ok！

the http response header returned on the browser

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Age 0
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date    Fri, 11 Dec 2015 01:50:57 GMT
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=C49D71942379289A803041B4257E6328; Path=/; HttpOnly
Vary    User-Agent
Via 1.1 varnish-v4
X-AREQUESTID    110x16852x1
X-ASEN  SEN-L4572887
X-AUSERNAME anonymous
X-Varnish   32779
x-content-type-options  nosniff
```

what's wrong with my settings? Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of you problem but I am pretty sure that you want to use return(lookup) and not return(pipe) in your VCL for your static content.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am using varnish 4, says "Invalid return "lookup" in subroutine "vcl_recv", Legal returns are: "hash" "pass" "pipe" "purge" "synth" "

Comment: use return(hash) for varnish 4

Comment: tried that, but didn't work, I think the problem is not caused by the static resources as the dynamic contents return empty, the requests definitely have reached the backend, but somehow lost in nginx or varnish. if i bypass nginx and go with varnish only, it works

Comment: As mentioned I am not sure if this is related to your current problem but in my opinion you still want to use "hash" instead of "pipe" in your VCL if you want to cache your static resources.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue. You might want to check that in your backend you are not really sending back a 304 response (avoid any cache your backend might try to do).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name jira.lan.mysite.com;
...
  location / { 
    ...
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    ...
  }
}
```

I had a similar issue and the problem was that nginx was using http/1.0 protocol as reverse proxy and looks this can't handle much well encoded chunk stuff.